# Overcoming LaTeX's bias towards packing text less in later parts of the document

Tags: formatting

Suppose that I am writing a manuscript with a 15-page limit.

As I'm sure many LaTeX users are aware, introducing a single line towards the end of a manuscript may result in me going over the page limit, whereas I might get away with adding an entire paragraph on page 1 without doing so.

Is there any "standard" way to avoid this bias? I see this unpredictable behavior as one of the key weaknesses of LaTeX, and simple Google searches did not offer up an obvious answer.

Comment: I surmise that the issue involves floats, tables, and other things besides text. Please clarify. Also may depend on whether you are using raggedbottom or flushbottom, and the value of some glues.

Comment: Actually I don't think the bias you describe is actually there. LaTeX will fill up _any_ page as much as possible, also the first one. So it may easily happen that adding a line on page one will shift the content of all following pages down. Of course it can happen that one of the pages in the middle has some space to spare and can "absorp" an extra line introduced on an earlier page. However, you can use this principle the other way around too: if the last page overflows, remove a few words in the middle causing that middle page to accommodate an extra paragraph and shifting everything up.

Comment: Moreover, with some experience you will become proficient in spotting where there is some space to be gained, and you can pack/compress the text with small edits allowing to stay within the page limit with limited (pun intended :D) effort.

Comment: I think that the bias is yours. LaTeX does what you tell it to do. ( See the other comments.) --- GOM

Comment: "As I'm sure many LaTeX users are aware," I have been maintaining latex for 30 years but I can not guess what bias you mean. Obviously a change at the start may affect all pages but a change at the end can only affect the end (latex does not have the whole document in memory) but I would call that "natural processing order" not "bias"

Comment: Right, I wasn’t sure how to phrase this exactly, but I do encounter this behavior in many instances and was wondering whether it can be avoided

Comment: You can avoid wasting spaces in pages,  but are you willing to pay the cost? For example, If you want to avoid also a widow line at the end of some page, it should be at the cost of increase spaces between paragraphs, or left an end gap, or reduce spaces between words.  Choose! BTW, from the manual introduction of  `savetrees` :  *The goal of the `savetrees` package is to pack as much text as possible onto each page of a LaTeX document.  **Admittedly, this makes the document far less attractive.***

Comment: IMHO the best strategy to save space is to ask someone to cross out all unnecessary words. The savings are usually surprisingly high for me. So this is IMHO not a LaTeX issue, even not a typography problem, but mainly a writing problem.

Comment: @cabohah to some extent it is a writing problem. However, sometimes the (near-)optimal version of the text in terms of content, clarity, completeness, examples, visualizations, references, just doesn't fit into some arbitrary page limit. You can try to rewrite further to leave some things out or to express them even more succinctly, but then the paper becomes incomplete or hard to read or both. In that case it _does_ become a LaTeX issue, i.e., how to cram your optimal text into the format set by the conference.

Comment: If you were to clarify your question it could be re-opened but I still can not guess what "it" is  when you say "whether it can be avoided"  surely it is clear if you change text at the start it may affect all pages, if you change text at the end after all but one page have been written out, you can only affect the last page.